# shopping cart ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

im using

```
def add_to_cart
  @cart = find_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @cart.add_product(product)
end
```

from a book.
this is to create a shopping cart.
what I don't understand is, do I need a controller for my cart? because without it,its giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you're not really sure how to use Rails.

Whether or not you need a controller for you cart is up to you, however I would have one.  That way you can have a "view your cart" page, as well as easily delete items.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/

Watch a few of those.  If you search for shopping cart (and related terms) you'll find a few episodes to watch.  I don't think there are any where he actually shows how to build one, but if you look at how he has things set up you can get a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you shouldn't need a controller unless you have a route for `Carts` inside your config/routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above method should definitely live inside a controller. The controller should look like this:

http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/code/depot_f/app/controllers/store_controller.rb